# Alternate proof of countable subadditivity of outer measures

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

The property of countable subadditivity of outer measures is

$$\mu^{*} \big( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k \big) \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu^* (A_k)  $$

where the definition of outer measures indicated is

$$\mu^* (A)= \inf \{ \sum_m \iota(C_m) \mid \{C_m\}_m\subseteq\mathcal{C}, A\subseteq\bigcup_m C_m \} $$ for non-empty $A\subseteq X$ and $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$. In this case, $\mathcal {C}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a semi-algebra of the set $X$ and $\iota \colon \mathcal C\to[0,\infty]$ is a set function satisfying $\iota(\emptyset)=0$, finite additivity over disjoint unions and countable subadditivity.

The text that I am referring to is "A Course in Real Analysis" by MacDonald and Weiss. The proof of countable subadditivity utilises $\epsilon$-room technique. Is there any alternate proof of countable subadditivity of outer measures which does not utilise $\epsilon$-room technique?

Comment: What definition of outer measure are you working with? For example in "G.B Folland-Real analysis" countable subadditivity is in the definition of outer measure. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure) Halmos(1950) also includes countable subadditivity in the definition of outer measure.

Comment: Yes, true. I have seen authors using both directions. That is, define outer measure to be a set function which is non-negative, monotone and countable subadditivity. Then $\mu^*$ above is an example of an outer measure. And conversely, set $\mu^*$ to be the definition of outer measure. Then prove that any outer measure will satisfy non-negativity, monotonicity and countable subadditivity.